# GDAL Merge Py on ubuntu many tif tiles into one

Tags: python, gdal, ubuntu, linux, gdal-merge

Trying to batch mosaic 1000 Gtiff rasters (all in one folder) into 1 tif file via gdal merge on linux ubuntu.

Having trouble with the linux command to bring in all files in a folder into the output tiff.

Looking for sample code for use in gdal on ubuntu in the terminal.

For Ubuntu my best guess is

```
for f in *.tiff; do gdal_merge -of GTiff "$f"; done
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Updated Question. John Barca

Comment: Answer posted. I hope that is what you wanted. You probably want to do a test with a few adjacent tiles first, as mosaicing 1000 tiles might take a while :D

Comment: Let me know if gdalwarp $(ls *.tif) output.tif works instead, and I will update the answer. I know you asked about gdal_merge, but gdalwarp seems to be a better solution for large volumens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gdal_merge.py -o output.tif `ls *.tif`
```

The back ticks mean execute whatever is inside the back ticks before the main command, so this will find all tif files in current directory, which will then be used as the input to gdal_merge.py.

Instead of backticks, you can also use the `$(command)` syntax, ie,

```
gdal_merge.py -o output.tif $(ls *.tif)
```

is equivalent to the previous.

If you have more complicated search requirements, you can use the unix/linux `find` command first in conjunction with ls to create a list to pass to gdal_merge.

I just did this successfully with 16 tiffs on ubuntu, so it certainly should work for you.

Comment: it looks, I am testing.

Comment: So when I run on even two tifs I get a memory error. 0...10...20...30...40...50Traceback
MemoryError

Comment: Perhaps use gdalwarp instead? gdal_merge copies files into memory first, whereas gdalwarp does this incrementally. Try, gdalwarp  $(ls *.tif) output.tif

Comment: Thanks, will try next week When I am on a PC. Never used warp to merge before. I assume I have to set the extents etc. manually

Comment: No, all read from the world files. Literally as simple as what I posted in the comments.

Comment: Have you given this a try yet. I'm interested to know how it scales.

Comment: I'm afraid it just never finished processing so I ran in through ArcGIS model builder in the end.  Created a raster and loaded each tile into it in batch. In GDAL defense the final raster was 617 GB.

Comment: :D. Fair enough. I suspect it would have finished in the end, then.